# Box Selection Categories selecting

Tags: html, css

Please check this Jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/0qvhr1yo/1/

What i want is to have some `<options>` Like Basket or Football> Get in the center (text:aligh: center) with Bold `<b></b>` So that is like a category in the whole box. Like a `<p></p>` . Unfortunately it doesnt accept any plain text or paragraph attributes. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `<optgroup>` tag for your list.  See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qvhr1yo/2/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Center

- workaround: use `indent` in CSS:

  ```
  text-indent: 10px;
  ```

2) Bold

- you can use: `font-weight` in CSS

  ```
  font-weight:bold;
  ```
- if you don't want it for every `<option>`, use `nth-child`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a css class to your `<option>` categories. E.g.

```
<option class="category">Football</option>
<option href="#">Champions League</option>
```

And then create a css rule like:

```
.category {
text-align:center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color:grey;
}
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0qvhr1yo/5/

Note that you will have to change your #cat css rule to `font-weight:normal` instead of `font-weight:600`, if you want the category to have a distinguishable different weight.

Comment: Actually text-aligh:center doesnt work but i can compromise :)